# How to change colors of points in Python's ggplot

Tags: python, plot, colors, python-ggplot

I'm trying to figure out how to change the colors that ggplot produces on my plot. In `label`, I have 4 categories - `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`. Currently ggplot colors these as purple, green, and red, but I would like to change it to shades of blue, with the exception of 0. To clarify, if for that point, the label in my pandas data frame is a `0`, then I want it to just be a gray colored point, if it's labeled `1`, a light blue, if it's `2`, normal shade of blue, and if it's `3` , then a dark blue.

(In case you're wondering why it only uses red, green, and purple, is because for my current data set, there are no points with the label `2`).

So far this is what I have:

```
gg = ggplot(aes('index', 'clicks', color = 'label'), data=xy_data) + \
     geom_point() +\
     xlab("Date") + ylab("Total clicks")
print gg
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use the scale_fill_brewer function:

```
gg = ggplot(aes('index', 'clicks', color = 'label'), data=xy_data) + \
     geom_point() +\
     ggplot.scale_fill_brewer() +\
     xlab("Date") + ylab("Total clicks")
print gg
```

By default scale_fill_brewer() displays different shades of blue but you can use different shades too by using palette argument inside scale_fill_brewer().

Comment: is `scale_fill_brewer()` for python? i'm getting an unresolved reference.

Comment: You have to import that too. It's a function in ggplot